# Block Windows from uploading updates to other PCs

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-v1903

What the title says. Is there a way to block Windows from ***uploading*** updates to other computers?

All I can find is an option to stop ***downloading*** from other computers, and an option to ***limit*** the amount uploaded. There doesn't seem to be a way to ***block*** uploading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have probably found the Windows option of
*Settings > Update & Security > Delivery Optimisation*, then setting to Off the
option of "Allow downloads from other PCs".

Once you've completed this step, your device will no longer *upload or
download updates* for Windows 10 or apps from other computers on the
local network or the internet. You'll still be able to obtain updates directly
from the Microsoft servers.

If you're just concerned about the upload usage, you can keep the
"Allow downloads from other PCs" toggled On, but select
"PCs on my local network". This will allow uploading updates, but only to
devices within your local network, not to the internet.

From Microsoft's
[Windows Update Delivery Optimization and privacy](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4468254/windows-update-delivery-optimization-faq):

> Make sure `Allow downloads from other PCs` is turned Off. You'll get updates and apps directly from Windows Update and from Microsoft Store with Delivery Optimization; however, you won’t download from or upload to other PCs.

Comment: Thanks. But do you have a source for that?

Comment: Sure - Microsoft. Added to the answer.

Comment: @ispiro - If the documentation is wrong, then that issue should be reported to Microsoft, but since we would all at the mercy of the documentation being incorrect.